# Python code -how to change each element of an array within a range when trying to find the subset

Tags: python

I would like to check if an array (`exp1`, `exp2`, `exp3`, ..) is a subset of another array `sim`, but the difference of elements can be within a range (+-2). Here is an example

```py
sim = [205.46,195.93,189.6,184.01,179.23,158.31,149.07,129.27,110.87,94.524,81.518,49.244,43.926,28.643]

exp1 = [190.61, 109.5, 42.323 ] # This is a subset
exp2 = [205, 28.6]              # This is a subset
exp3 = [88]                     # This is NOT a subset
exp4=[208.14, 125.162, 186.2]   # This is NOT a subset
```

I found this code to easily find the subset but I don't know how to include the range between +2 and -2.

```py
# Return 1 if arr2[] is a subset of
# arr1[]
def isSubset(arr1, arr2, m, n):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(m):
            if(arr2[i] == arr1[j]):
                break
        
        # If the above inner loop was
        # not broken at all then arr2[i]
        # is not present in arr1[]
        if (j == m):
            return 0

    # If we reach here then all
    # elements of arr2[] are present
    # in arr1[]
    return 1

# Driver code
if __name__ == "__main__":
    arr1 = [11, 1, 13, 21, 3, 7]
    arr2 = [11, 3, 7, 1]
    m = len(arr1)
    n = len(arr2)
    if(isSubset(arr1, arr2, m, n)):
        print("arr2[] is subset of arr1[] ")
    else:
        print("arr2[] is not a subset of arr1[]")
```

After I find a way to do that then I will loop over sim arrays like sim1, sim2, ...
Here I am trying to compare a set of simulation results with a set of experimental ones which the error bar is within +-2.
I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to add this comparative sentence in conditional statement in the `isSubset` function:

```py
if (arr2[i] >= arr1[j]-2 and arr2[i] <= arr1[j]+2):
  break
```

Also you can make the process more efficient:

```py
for i in range(n):
  for j in range (m):
    if (arr2[i] >= arr1[j]-2 and arr2[i] <= arr1[j]+2):
      break
    if j == m-1:
      return 0
```

In python, you do not need any declaration for the `for` loop, because python just loop from 0 to the m-1 by default.

Comment: Dear Dhana, I am sorry. There was a problem in my information: exp1=[190.61, 109.5, 42.323 ] --> subset exp2=[205, 28.6] --> subset exp3=[88] --> not a subset  exp4=[208.14, 125.162, 186.2] --> not a subset

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it didn't work. It just gives back "subset" and doesn't recognize the "non-subset" inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change function `isSubset()` a bit.

```py
# Return True if arr2[] is a subset of arr1[], with specified error
def isSubset(arr1, arr2, error):
    for a2 in arr2:
        found = False
        for a1 in arr1:
            if(abs(a1 - a2) < error):
                found = True
                break
        if not found:
            return False
    return True
```

Instead of comparing indexes I iterated over array with `in` and saved a variable checking if solution is found, in specified `error` boundaries - for your example its `2`.

```
# Driver code
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sim = [205.46,195.93,189.6,184.01,179.23,158.31,149.07,129.27,110.87,94.524,81.518,49.244,43.926,28.643]

    exp1 = [190.61, 109.5, 42.323 ] # This is a subset
    exp2 = [205, 28.6]              # This is a subset
    exp3 = [88]                     # This is NOT a subset
    exp4 = [208.14, 125.162, 186.2] # This is NOT a subset

    print(isSubset(sim, exp1, 2)) # True
    print(isSubset(sim, exp2, 2)) # True
    print(isSubset(sim, exp3, 2)) # False
    print(isSubset(sim, exp4, 2)) # False
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried your suggestion but it didn't work. It just gives back "subset" and doesn't recognize the "non-subset" inputs.

Comment: @Marla Updated answer so now it works for your example

Answer (score 0):

How big is the dataset? If it's not too big you can solve it with a cool modification - instead of looking at a list of values you can create a list of ranges from the original data.

```
sim = [205.46, 195.93, 189.6, 184.01, 179.23, 158.31, 149.07, 129.27, 110.87, 94.524, 81.518, 49.244, 43.926, 28.643]
exp1 = [190.61, 109.5, 42.323]
exp4 = [208.14, 125.162, 186.2]

sim_range = [(x - 2, x + 2) for x in sim]

def check_if_in_range(exp):
    for num in exp:
        if not any(r[0] <= num <= r[1] for r in sim_range):
            return False

        return True


print(check_if_in_range(exp1))
print(check_if_in_range(exp4))
```

Output is:

```
True
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone. The problem was (j == m) and I changed it to (j == m-1). Also I take care of the +-2 eror bar with (abs(arr2[i] - arr1[j])<=2) Here is the code that works perfect:

```
# Python 3 program to find whether an array 
# is subset of another array 

# Return 1 if arr2[] is a subset of  
# arr1[]  
def isSubset(arr1, arr2, m, n):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(m):
            if(abs(arr2[i] - arr1[j])<=2):
                break

        # If the above inner loop was 
        # not broken at all then arr2[i] 
        # is not present in arr1[]  
            if j == m-1:
                return 0

    # If we reach here then all 
    # elements of arr2[] are present 
    # in arr1[]  
        return 1

# Driver code 
if __name__ == "__main__":

    arr1 = [11, 1, 13, 21, 3, 7]
#    arr2 = [7, 11, 1, 13] 
    arr2 = [2,9]
    m = len(arr1)
    n = len(arr2)

    if(isSubset(arr1, arr2, m, n)):
        print("arr2[] is  subset of arr1[] ")
    else:
        print("arr2[] is not a subset of arr1[]")
```